# Fixed point theorems including some linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

I am having a trouble with applying the fixed point theorem.
For instance, suppose I have three value functions.

Two of them are linear differential equations where $r \in (0,1)$ is a discount factor.

$rJ(x)= f(V(x),J'(x))$

$rH(x)= g(V(x),H'(x))$

$rV(x) = z(J(x),H(x))$

I am finding $V(x)$ which solves the above three equations at the same time, and suppose I have all necessary initial values.

In my real problem, I could find one, and now I want to show this solution is indeed unique.

I would appreciate to hear some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is to deal only with the differential equations. substituting $V$ in the first two equations, you get something of the type
$$
\begin{cases}
F(J(x),J'(x),H(x)) = 0\\
G(J(x),H(x),H'(x)) = 0,
\end{cases}
$$

which is a system of first order differential equations. Although most of the existence and uniqueness results are for differential equations where the derivative appears in an explicit way, you may explore/assume properties of $F,G$ to argue that the system can be written in the form

$$
\begin{cases}
J'(x) = \tilde F(J(x),H(x))\\
H'(x) = \tilde G(J(x),H(x)),
\end{cases}
$$

at this point you can use the Picard-Lindelof theorem.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I will look through the theorem. Just to be clear, the Picard-Lindelof theorem can be applied for the system of differential equation as well?

Comment: Yes, the Picard theorem can be applied to systems in the form $y' = f(x,y)$, with $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.